# Issues adding colour aesthetic to geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to add a colour aesthetic to my geom_point, which depicts the year the datapoint was taken. I've attempted the `colour =` and `fill =` but have provided less than desirable results. I think this is primarily to do with calling for the column names to be the colour aesthetic (this should make more sense if you look at the df)

[image: geom_point]

Here is my code and df to produce the plot (Note: I attempted colour = "State" knowing it would be wrong. **But I'm unaware how to produce the result I want which would be a colour for "2017" and a different colour for "2015"):**

```
p3 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Unemployment_picked, -c("State", "Counties"), names_to = "Unemployment_picked", values_to = "num") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=State, y=num, point = num, fill = "State")) + 
  geom_point(stat="identity")

p3 + labs(x = "State",
      y = "Unemployment Rate %",
      title = "US State Unemployment Rate") + 
  geom_line()+ geom_text(aes(label = round(num,2)), hjust=-.2, vjust=1)
```

```
structure(list(State = structure(c(3L, 5L, 14L, 33L, 45L, 49L
), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", 
              "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", 
              "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", 
              "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", 
              "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", 
              "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", 
              "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", 
              "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", 
              "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
              "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
              "Wyoming"), class = "factor"), Counties = c(15L, 58L, 102L, 62L, 
                                                          254L, 39L), UE_15 = c(11.9666666666667, 10.8, 7.97450980392157, 
                                                                                7.85806451612903, 6.73818897637795, 8.84102564102564), UE_17 = c(9.76666666666667, 
                                                                                                                                                 8.26551724137931, 6.61176470588235, 6.57741935483871, 6.02834645669291, 
                                                                                                                                                 6.7025641025641)), row.names = c(3L, 5L, 14L, 33L, 45L, 49L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try removing the double quotes from `fill = "State"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tidiest solution is probably one more `pivot_`:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(UE_15:UE_17, names_to = "Year", values_to = "num") %>% 
  mutate(Year = gsub(".*(\\d{2}$)", "20\\1", .$Year)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=State, y=num, col = Year)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = State, col = NULL))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need two datasets for your plot. I call the one you attached `df1`, see below.

```
library(ggplot2)
df2 <- reshape(df1, idvar = "State", varying = c("UE_15", "UE_17"), direction = "long", sep = "_", timevar = "Year")

ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(data = df1, aes(x = State, xend = State, y = UE_15, yend = UE_17)) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = State, y = UE, color = as.factor(Year)), size = 3)
```

[image]

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(State = structure(c(3L, 5L, 14L, 33L, 45L, 49L
), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", 
"Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", 
"Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", 
"Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", 
"Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", 
"Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", 
"New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", 
"Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", 
"South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
"Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
"Wyoming"), class = "factor"), Counties = c(15L, 58L, 102L, 62L, 
254L, 39L), UE_15 = c(11.9666666666667, 10.8, 7.97450980392157, 
7.85806451612903, 6.73818897637795, 8.84102564102564), UE_17 = c(9.76666666666667, 
8.26551724137931, 6.61176470588235, 6.57741935483871, 6.02834645669291, 
6.7025641025641)), row.names = c(3L, 5L, 14L, 33L, 45L, 49L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

structure(list(State = structure(c(3L, 5L, 14L, 33L, 45L, 49L), .Label = c(
  "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California",
  "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia",
  "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana",
  "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland",
  "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri",
  "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey",
  "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio",
  "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island",
  "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah",
  "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin",
  "Wyoming"
), class = "factor"), Counties = c(
  15L, 58L, 102L, 62L,
  254L, 39L
), UE_15 = c(
  11.9666666666667, 10.8, 7.97450980392157,
  7.85806451612903, 6.73818897637795, 8.84102564102564
), UE_17 = c(
  9.76666666666667,
  8.26551724137931, 6.61176470588235, 6.57741935483871, 6.02834645669291,
  6.7025641025641
)), row.names = c(3L, 5L, 14L, 33L, 45L, 49L), class = "data.frame") -> Unemployment_picked


ggplot(Unemployment_picked, aes(x = State)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = UE_15, ymax = UE_17)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = UE_15), color = "red") +
  geom_text(aes(y = UE_15, label = round(UE_15, 2)), hjust=-.2, vjust=1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = UE_17), color = "blue") +
  geom_text(aes(y = UE_17, label = round(UE_17,2)), hjust=-.2, vjust=1) + 
  labs(x = "State",
       y = "Unemployment Rate %",
       title = "US State Unemployment Rate")
```

Comment: That's great! Is there a way to get the legend back in the visualisation, however?